# Marketing Cloud Triggered Emails with Custom Variable

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

I have a triggered email I’d like to pass a custom variable to. I’m triggering the email via the RESTful API and JSON.

I've tried inserting `%%dateandtime%%` and `%%[dateandtime]%%` into my email with JSON like so.

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "someone@internet.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "someone@internet.com",
        "dateandtime" : "May 5, 2017",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {

            }
        }
    },
    "OPTIONS": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. What do I need in my JSON and what token do I need to insert into my email? Is there something additional I need?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the subscriber attributes?  Like here:https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html

Answer (score 1):

You should add/ update subscribers in All Subscribers or Data Extension first. Do this along With this custom attribute.
Then your email will be able to pick it up.

Check the below link on how to insert in a data extension using REST API

[Upserting Data Extension](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html)

Once records is loaded in the DE, refer them simply by %%columnname%% in the email

Comment: I created a data extension like so (http://imgur.com/12KvRnO). How do I reference this in my email and where should I pass it in my JSON?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that helps

Comment: What do you mean “once a record is loaded”? This data is coming into the API via JSON when I call https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:reservation-itinerary/send. The %%dateandtime%% variable, that I would like to map to my Data Extension, is not available in my email. What do I have to do for this variable to appear in the dropdown list?

Comment: Hi Alex, that drop-down only shows the attributes from All Subscribers. It cannot source from a data extension. 
Let me ask this - This variable - %%dateandtime%% , Is this an attribute in your data extension or ALL Subscribers?